# ¿Cual es la mejor técnica para realizar procesos de forma asíncrona en C#?

Tags: c#, hilos, asincronismo

Necesito consolidar información de mas de 100 sucursales en una BD central, la ventaja es que existen enlaces hacia cada una de ellas, yo desarrolle una tarea que básicamente extrae información y la inserta en el servidor central, pero actualmente la tengo funcionando como una cola. Intenté aplicar threads y tasks pero no me ha funcionado como he querido ya que en el caso de los threads cuando da un problema el proceso se quedan colgados y no terminaba de ejecutar todo, en el caso de utilizar un task de 10 ejecuta unas 2.

Esta es la forma de como esta actualmente con task:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("--INICIO DEL PROCESO. {0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}", HORA_INICIAL);

        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine();
        DateTime inicio = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan timeTot;
        DataSet dsTiendas = getTiendas();

        //DataSet dsProcedures = getProcedimientos();
        int sizeT = dsTiendas.Tables["Tienda"].Rows.Count;
        //int sizeP = dsProcedures.Tables["Procedure"].Rows.Count;
        int i;
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>(); 
        string serverDb, dataBase, procedure, tienda = "";
        if (sizeT > 0)
        {

            OpenConnection(true);
            for (i = 0; i < sizeT; i++)
            {
                serverDb = dsTiendas.Tables["Tienda"].Rows[i]["DIRECCIONIP"].ToString();
                dataBase = dsTiendas.Tables["Tienda"].Rows[i]["DB_GENESIS"].ToString();
                procedure = dsTiendas.Tables["Tienda"].Rows[i]["SP_NOMBRE"].ToString();

                tienda = dsTiendas.Tables["Tienda"].Rows[i]["U_TIENDA"].ToString() + ": " + dsTiendas.Tables["Tienda"].Rows[i]["NOMBRE"].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Incio de Ejecucion de procesos Tienda: " + tienda);
                Console.WriteLine("IP: " + serverDb);                

                Console.WriteLine("Procedimiento: " + procedure);
                Console.WriteLine("--Inicio del proceso. {0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now);

                Task Tarea = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ejecutarNonQuery("EXEC " + procedure + " '" + serverDb + "', '" + dataBase + "', '" + procedure + "'"));



                taskList.Add(Tarea);
                Console.WriteLine("--Fin del proceso. {0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now);




            }
            Console.WriteLine("Fin de la tarea " + tienda);
            timeTot = DateTime.Now - inicio;
            Console.WriteLine("--Hora finalizada. {0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine("--Tiempo transcurrido en minutos: {00}", timeTot.Minutes);

        }

        // Esperar a que se ejecuten todas las consultas antes de cerrar la conexión
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());

        CloseConnection(true);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);
    }
```

Comment: Eche un vistazo a "async" y "await"

Comment: Hola Jose, siento que el problema que tienes con los Task van por el lado de la ejecución de los StoreProcedures, aqui tienes una idea de como manejar los errores usando Tasks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983779/catch-exception-that-is-thrown-in-different-thread espero te sea de utilidad

Comment: que base de datos utilizas ?

Answer (score 1):

Si la idea es sincronizar datos con el volumnen de suscursales que mencionas realizarlo desde codigo no es aconsejable.

Podrias aplicar algunas de estas tecnicas

- Usar la replicacion que porporciona la base de datos, si usas Sql Server esta permite replicar desde y hacia sucursales

[Replicación de SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms151198%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

- Usar `SyncFramework`

[Introduction to Microsoft Sync Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992.aspx)

este ultimo si se realiza desde codigo pero las tareas de sincronizacion son transparentes.